# Issue with YouTube Java API

Tags: java, youtube-api

I am using YouTube API to perform simple searches on YouTube. Here's my code :

```
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeQuery;
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService;

/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author denzilc
 *
 */
public class CollectData {

    public static String clientID = "****";
    public static String developer_key = "*****";
    public static String YOUTUBE_URL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos";

    public static String myQuery = "India";
    public static int maxResults = 200;
    public static int timeout = 2000;


    public static String outputDir = "";
    public static String outputFile = "";




    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clientID);
            YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(new URL(YOUTUBE_URL));

            query.setSafeSearch(YouTubeQuery.SafeSearch.NONE);




        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

However, I receive the following compilation error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The type com.google.gdata.client.Query
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class
>   files CollectData.java    /YouTube/src    line
>   1 Java Problem

Here's a pic of my JAVA Build Path and the referenced libraries:[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `gdata-client-core-1.0.jar`